# Saml ReturnUrl lost when proxy involved

Tags: .net-core, sustainsys-saml2

I am using Sustainsys.Saml2 for authentication in my environment. It has worked well until I added a proxy into the loop.

The data flow is:

1) User navigates to site via proxy server (example.mysite.com)

2) Proxy forwards to internal application (example.internal.mysite.com)

3) Saml does its thing, forwards to service for `authenticate` and `redirect` 
step

4) **Weird part**: The saml response is sent back to the original host hitting Saml2/Acs (example.mysite.com/Saml2/Acs) and responding as a 303 -- the assumption is that it should be 303'ing to example.mysite.com, but instead it's to the proxy host name at example.internal.mysite.com

Why is it doing that? It doesn't seem to be respecting the ReturnUrl (which is example.mysite.com). I see no evidence of the proxy URL from requests/responses during the auth process until #4.

Answer (score 1):

The Sustainsys.Saml2 library builds various URLs from what it sees in the incoming HTTP Request. When a proxy is involved, that might *not* be the same URL as the client sees.

There's a setting `PublicOrigin` that you can set to handle this, that will override any host found in the request.

However, in The AspNetCore2 handler it is assumed that this has already been fixed in the Request object, before the handler is invoked. This is usually done automatically by the hosting environment if hosting in Kestrel behind IIS or similar.

Comment: The PublicOrigin is set and as far as I can tell is properly added as an SPOption

Comment: Can you pinpoint where in the lifecycle of an Acs command execution that PublicOrigin is being used to enforce the 303 location?

Comment: I added some logging in the GetLocation method at https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/blob/master/Sustainsys.Saml2/WebSSO/AcsCommand.cs#L108 -- it shows that the SPOptions.ReturnUrl is *GOOD*, but the storedRequestState.RetrurnUrl is *BAD*, bad as in it's using the proxy host url.

Comment: I modified the GetLocation method to return SPOptions.ReturnUrl if it isn't null and the acs command now 303s to the correct URL. Is there a bug regarding Acs/PublicOrigin/storedRequestState?

Comment: Digging a bit more, I see that the publicOrigin is correctly pulled in the SignInCommand.Run method in the call to Saml2Urls, however that doesn't seem to get used. Later in the same method a variable called returnUrl is defined that uses the returnPath param. In my logs I see that returnPath is the internal url.

Comment: I should note this is for AspNetCore2. The AspNetCore2.Saml2Handler.ChallengeAsync is using the CurrentUri property to propagate the returnUrl. Should properties.RedirectUri be populated?

Comment: Edited with some info on AspNetCore2. It doesn't use PublicOrigin because it shouldn't have to - the public URL is usually already fixed in the Request object.

Comment: What about in cases of a proxy? In that situation would the request object contain host information that is the proxy -- leading to a 303 Location sent back to the origin pointing to the internal location?

Comment: I found an issue that proposes a fix for this https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/issues/1064